# Disable auto-login on 16.04 when connecting via serial console?

Tags: 16.04, serial-port, auto-login

I have an ARM server running Ubuntu 16.04. I am connecting to the machine via the serial port.

When I reboot the system, it automatically logs in as root, without the usual username/password prompt. This is what I see after it completes the usual bootup stuff:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS ubuntu ttyAMA0

ubuntu login: root (automatic login)

Last login: Thu Mar  1 08:07:07 UTC 2018 on ttyAMA0
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.8.0-32-t99-perf aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

50 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.


root@ubuntu:~#
```

How can I configure it so it prompts for the username/password instead?

Comment: Maybe [you have to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27426789/4970442) `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`, check [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120628212412/http://linux.koolsolutions.com:80/2009/04/30/autologin-linux-console-mode).

Comment: I looked at this file, however a diff between it and the same file on a similar system (which does NOT auto-login) shows they are identical

Answer (score 3):

@Pablo Bianchi's comment was close... It turns out the file I needed to edit was:

```
/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service
```

Specifically change this line:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

to:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

Hurrah for grepping blindly and arriving at a solution!